# Find singularities and residues

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it possible to use a contour integral in complex plane argument for the following integral in order to turn it into an integral along the imaginary line?

Please help me find the singularities of the integrand and their residues.

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dT\left(\frac{m\omega}{2\pi i\hbar\sin\left(\omega T\right)}\right)^{1/2}\exp\left(-\frac{im\omega x_0^2}{\hbar}\tan\left(\omega T/2\right)+i\lambda T/\hbar\right)
\end{equation}
where $m$, $\omega$ and $\hbar$ are positive constants.

Thank you.

Comment: I think $m,\omega,\hbar,\lambda,x_0,i$ are all constants, right?

Comment: yeah they are positive. And $i$ is the imaginary $i$.